# System.IO.Directory.Delete v Git Repository - Unauthorized access

Tags: vb.net, git

I'm writing a piece of software that maintains files in a Git repository.

One of the executables I've written has one simple purpose: delete everything to do with the software. It is given to the user in a separate, completely unrelated Windows folder.

One of the folders it needs to delete contains a Git repository, i.e. it contains a hidden .git folder

Now here's the problem I'm having. When I'm on the PC itself looking at the file system I can find that folder, click on it, delete it .... and it's gone. Not a problem.

So I try to do the same thing in my assembly by calling **System.IO.Directory.Delete** on that folder.

Here is what I am finding:

1. Everything is removed from the folder, but the folder itself is still there
2. When I try to THEN manually delete the folder from Windows Explorer it gives me some Unauthorised Access message. I cannot delete it.
3. The only way to actually get rid of it is to then try RENAME the folder in Windows Explorer, at which point I once again get an Unauthorized Access message but wouldn't you know it.... the folder disappears.

What gives!?!? Why does a System.IO.Directory.Delete NOT do exactly the same thing as me going in through Windows Explorer and deleting the folder manually?

I have tried a number of things. For example I tried getting all the files in the directory and setting all their Attributes to Normal, and through all the folders and setting their Attributes to Directory And Not Hidden. Still no joy. I even tried using **Process.Start** to run a **RMDIR folder /S /Q** - which runs perfectly from a .bat file - but the same thing happens.

I do have TortoiseGit and all its dependencies installed in case that has anything to do with anything.... and the folder does have the green Tick on it to indicate that its content is all up to date.

**So my question is:**
Is there any way I can successfully delete a folder containing a Git repository though VB.NET?

Comment: do you perhaps set the directory as the working directory in your application?

Comment: No ... The "reset" application is completely separate from the folder I'm trying to remove. None of the software I'm trying to remove is running.

Comment: Perhaps this problem is caused by services running for TortoiseGit and/or Git itself? If so, what are these services? Can I temporarily stop them?

Comment: @ikkentim - I found the solution - see my answer below.

I am still setting all file attributes and folder attributes to Normal c.q. Directory and Not Hidden before deleting the folder but if it ain't broke ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got to the bottom of this mysterious mystery.

The culprit is TortoiseGit

When I killed the **TGitCache.exe** process just before deleting the folder, everything worked perfectly.

Go figure.